# converting method to Observable, still uses main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I am moving a pinging function to an observable so that it can be used with RxJava. It seems the call is still on the main thread and locking up the ui. Thoughts on what needs to be done to improve, did i even convert it correctly? I think it may be because of the **new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);**

```
public Observable<Boolean> isReachable(final String host, final int maxPings) {

    return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) -> {

        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try
                {
                    for (int i=0; i < maxPings; i++) {
                        Process ipAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + host);
                        int exitValue = ipAddrProcess.waitFor();
                        if (exitValue == 0) {
                            subscriber.onNext(Boolean.TRUE);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    subscriber.onNext(Boolean.FALSE);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                    return;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ignore)
                {
                    ignore.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);

    });
}
```

calling it like so

```
UtilsManager.getInstance().isReachable(Constants.SomeAddress, Constants.MaxPings)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    (reachable) -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Is it Reachable:" + reachable);
                    },
                    (error) -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got Error:" + error.getMessage());

                    },
                    () -> {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Completed Reachable");
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` specifies on which thread *onSubscribe* method will be called, which in your case is the whole part in *Observable.create()* method. However, you're posting your *Runnable* on main looper anyway - `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);` . So the task posting is done on one of Schedulers.io thread, but the Runnable itself is processed on Main Thread via Main Looper.
I suggest removing posting part and Runnable, just keep the body of runnable

Comment: thanks, you are right, i posted my answer just as you did yours.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by creating the Observable this way, posting to mainlooper was the cause as mentioned by krp:

```
public Observable<Boolean> isReachable(final String host, final int maxPings) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try
            {
                for (int i=0; i < maxPings; i++) {
                    Process ipAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + host);
                    int exitValue = ipAddrProcess.waitFor();
                    if (exitValue == 0) {
                        subscriber.onNext(Boolean.TRUE);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                subscriber.onNext(Boolean.FALSE);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
                return;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignore)
            {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```